# Как использовать almsaeedstudio.com в laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пример использования (описание(рус)) сервиса Almsaeed Studio в laravel 5.2 или просто описание, которое поможет разобраться.
Cпасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как использовать AdminLTE тему?
https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE (не на русском, но и так понятно)